# Blue prism - windows press keys

Tags: sendkeys, blueprism

I am trying to download a PDF from a website.

Below are my steps.

1. Click Download button from the site.
2. Checking for Save popup, If exists using global send keys to manipulate the saving functionality.(ALT+N -> TAB -> DOWNKEY+A)
3. Now SAVE AS window(Windows Explorer) appears.

Here i Would like to use Global sendkeys to paste the folder name in address bar. But i am not able to get the "Global send keys" under action column in Navigate stage. Instead i could find actions like Windows press key, Windows press key with Alt, Global mouse click and so on...

Could any one help me to understand how to use WindowsPressKey feature in Blueprism. Does the keystroke works the same way as Global send keys?

**eg for Global Sendkeys event:**

**To type Hello:**
"<{SHIFT}H>{SHIFT}ello"

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**
According to BP documentation: yes. BUT depending on your BP version the syntax could be different.
With the release of v6.2 (again according to BP documentation) they've streamlined the 'key' syntax.
That being said I have NEVER gotten the v6.2 syntax to work on v6.2

**Real Answer**
According to best practices the WindowsPressKey, EventPressKey, and GlobalPressKey should only be used as a last resort, and in that order.

While I have found GlobalPressKey to work consistently and as expected I have never had any consistent nor doc-promised results using the WindowsPressKey.

For the scenario you outlined any kind of send key is really not the answer.
What should be done is the building of a broad 'Internet Explorer' Win32 object that addresses things that might be encountered in an Browser application model.
This means pop-ups, browser prompts, save menus, etc.

This will enable your process to detach/attach between IE instances as you encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is:

1. Global Send Keys "%s" for ALT+S after getting the Save Popup. It will save the file in default downloads location.
2. Move file(s) using "Utility - File Management" from default downloads location to wherever you want.

This is working consistently for me. As a thumb rule, try to avoid dependency on applications and do more through built-in code based functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is asking for a response to

```
to understand how to use WindowsPressKey feature in Blueprism
```

However I would like to draw attention to the actual action you are automating and offer a different solution that is more robust. When a browser spawns a window to download an item you can spy that window and interact with, similarly when the browser spawns a file explorer window to indicate where to save something you can create an object for that too and integrate with it. This gets rid of the need to deal with button presses etc. and just focus on integrating with the underlying system. Would advise you to create some new object(s) to interact with the underlying applications, this would alleviate alot of issues in the future and give you a good stable solution.